# Every complete axiomatizable theory is decidable

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Enderton (in *A Mathematical Introduction to Logic*) gives the following theorems:

> **Theorem $17$F** : A set of expressions is decidable iff both it and its complement (relative to the set of all expressions) are effectively enumerable.
>
> ---
>
> **Theorem $17$G** : If $\Sigma$ is a decidable set of wffs, then the set of tautological consequences of $\Sigma$ is effectively enumerable.

Are those two theorems enough to prove the following claim?

> **Claim**: Every complete axiomatizable theory is decidable.

---

**My attempt** : let $T$ be an axiomatizable theory, such that there is a decidable set $\Sigma$ of sentences such that $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)=T$ (where $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)$ is the deductive closure of $\Sigma$). Since $\Sigma$ is decidable, then by **Theorem $17$G**, the set of its tautological consequences is effectively enumerable. But this set is precisely $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)$, therefore $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)$ is effectively enumerable. Thus, by **Theorem $17$F**, $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)$ is decidable. Finally, since $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)=T$, $T$ is decidable.

I think my application of **Theorem $17$F** is not correct, since I haven't shown that the complement of $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma)$ is also effectively enumerable. How can I do that? I guess I have to use the fact that $T$ is a complete theory, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: See **Coroll 26I**, page 157.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Well, yes, but that brings me back to **Coroll 25F** and **Coroll 25G** of the **enumerability theorem** (page 142), which is (more or less) equivalent to **theorem 17G**. That seems a bit circular to me. Can we show the claim in question using only the two theorems stated in the question?

Comment: Exactly : **Coroll 25G** : "for any sentence $\sigma$ either $\Gamma \vDash \sigma$ or $\Gamma \vDash \lnot \sigma$. Then the set of sentences implied by $\Gamma$ is decidable." But this (see page 156) is guaranteed by the fact that $\mathsf{Cn}(\Gamma)=T$ is *complete*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA That makes perfect sense, thank you :) I just realised that my lecturer used a different definition of $\mathsf{Cn}$ than Enderton, hence my confusion.

Comment: I see ... :) From you previous post, I deduce that $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma) = \{ \phi \mid \Sigma \vdash \phi \}$. But, for prop logic as well as f-o logic, by *completeness* this is equivalent to : $\mathsf{Cn}(\Sigma) = \{ \phi \mid \Sigma \vDash \phi \}$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA This is indeed the convention adopted by my lecturer. So I could technically use said convention for the proof, if I added the completeness step, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** since the theory is complete, for any sentence $\sigma$, $\sigma \not \in Cn(\Sigma) \iff \neg \sigma \in Cn(\Sigma)$.

Comment: Ohhh, right. I think I got a bit confused because my lecturer uses the syntactic definition of $\mathsf{Cn}$ whereas Enderton uses the semantic one. Thanks!